# How to disable mouse acceleration on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, dconf

My mouse has mouse acceleration and is too fast in ubuntu 18.04.
Creating `90-mouse.conf` in `xorg.conf.d` doesn't work.
And when gnome will switch from [xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg) to [wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/), these `xorg.conf` files wont work anymore.
Is there another way to disable mouse acceleration in ubuntu?

Answer (score 25):

Ubuntu uses [gnome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) and gnome uses [dconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf)(a "database" full of settings).

**How to:**

- Install dconf-editor

  - `sudo apt install dconf-editor` via terminal or
  - search for `Dconf Editor` in Ubuntu Software
- Open the dconf-editor and go to `org` -> `gnome` -> `desktop` -> `peripherals` -> `mouse`

Here are the mouse settings.

- **accel-profile** -> sets what kind of acceleration you want to have
- **speed** -> sets the mouse speed

You have these options in **accel-profile**:

- **default**
- **flat** aka. disable mouse acceleration
- **adaptive**

To disable mouse acceleration:

- set `Use default value` to `off`
- set `Custom value` to `flat`

To change the mouse speed:

- go to `org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/speed`
- set `Use default value` to `off`
- change the `Custom value` to the number that works for you
  (the number can be between -1 and 1)

Comment: This doesn't affect Lubuntu or other flavors.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution that you can use directly from the terminal with the `gsettings` command.

```sh
# displays what this setting represents
gsettings describe org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile

# displays the values it accepts as input
gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile

# sets the accelleration profile to 'flat'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile 'flat'
```

I came to this solution because I stumbled on https://developer.gnome.org/GSettings/#gsettings which says.

> For modifying the dconf backend storage itself, use the dconf tool; but gsettings should be used by preference.

The commands in this answer uses gsettings instead of dconf.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065543/250300) didn't help me (maybe because of MATE), here is another solution:

> The graphical setting is unitialized. Move both acceleration and
>   sensitivity to middle and then click close. Reopen the mouse
>   preferences and adjust acceleration and sensitivity as you need.

Reference:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/mouse-too-fast-in-18-04-again-known-methods-stopped-working/18805