# How to fix mouse Lag Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mouse

Got some mouse lag in Ubuntu 18.04. Had it for a while now and just have kind of put up with it, but I need to get deeper into Ubuntu and linux which means actually trying to find solutions to all these weird linuxy problems.

I have a dual boot i5 integrated graphics ultra-book + Steel series rival 600. Silky smooth performance under windows, laggy under ubuntu, seems to be more laggy when moving between screens, but I am still not sure if it is a peak in GPU or CPU causing the problem. (Mouse completely stopped just now when I pressed "Review your question".)

I have tried changing USB port. I have tried quitting programs in the taskbar such as Teams and f.lux. I have also tried the following fix which seemed to help somewhat but not completely:

[How can I get rid of mouse lag under Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763413/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mouse-lag-under-ubuntu)

Is this just linux being linux or is this the excuse I need to splash out on a new a faster PC?

TIA any input is appreciated!

Comment: Neither "*Linux being Linux*" nor an excuse to splash out: I can run Ubuntu on a tiny lightweight Raspberry Pi without mouse lag. Beware of trying random shell incantations - don't do it until you understand what it does, how to measure it's effect, and how to undo it.

Comment: Have you tried disabling mouse acceleration either through System Settings -> Mouse if not using Gnome or through dconf-editor GUI app or gsettings terminal command [as per the answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1065542/411468) or [gnome-tweaks](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-tweaks) which is another GUI app?